# How Python converts string to integer

Tags: python, built-in, built-in-types

This question is not about usage of `int` function, but rather how it is done internally.

Because source code is in C I don't understand what is going on there.

Maybe someone can explain how Python convert string `"123"` to integer `123`.
What operations are performed for it?

Comment: Could you provide the C function so we don't have to go search for it ourselves?

Comment: "I want to understand how it works but I don't understand the language it is written in and want you to explain it to me instead of learning it" is how I interpreted this question.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, please consider updating your interpreter

Comment: You clearly know how SO works, your question is clear and to the point which is good, you just don't give enough information about what aspect of the implementation you are interested in.  If you were interested in the [tag:algorithm] you would have used the tag, if you were interested in the extra steps it takes (stripping whitespace, reading sign etc.) then that would have been specified.  I think if you edited your question to be a bit more precise you will likely get an answer better suited to what you are looking for. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2d305e1c46abfcd609bf8b2dff8d2065e6af8ab2/Objects/longobject.c#L2075-L2366 contains the implementation you're looking for. While understanding the C is useful, there is a large comment in the middle (starting on line 2132) that explains much of the approach.

Answer (score 2):

When converting a python string to an int, e.g. `a = int("123",10)`, (convert the string "123" to an integer in base 10) a C function is is called.

First, it checks that the given counting base base is >= 2 and <=36, or 0. (Error otherwise)
Next, it ignores all leading spaces. (so that `"   123" = "123"`),
and check if the number is marked as positive `'+'`, or negative `'-'`

When the base is 0, it checks if the string starts with `'0x','0o', '0b', '0'`, and sets the base respectively (hexadecimal, octal, binary, decimal).
Note that if no base is given, then the default base is 10 (Decimal).

It then proceeds to turning the character array into a number, using the algorithm described in the code comment at the [link posted by Paul Kehrer](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2d305e1c46abfcd609bf8b2dff8d2065e6af8ab2/Objects/longobject.c#L2075-L2366)

Trailing spaces are also ignored, and Errors are raised if needed- for example if there's a space in the middle of the string, followed by a number, or if there's a non-number character.